# How can I parse the output of lshw using Perl regexes?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse [`lshw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/lshw.1.html) output into a hash with this code, what works so far.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my (%lshw,$key,$value);
  while (<>){
  s/#.*//;                # no comments
  s/^\s+//;               # no leading whites
  s/\s+$//;               # no trailing whites
  next unless length;     # anything left?
  if (/(?<key>.*?):\s+(?<value>.*)/x){
    $lshw{$+{key}} = $+{value};
  }
}

# remove white spaces in hash keys
for $key (keys %lshw){
  $value = delete $lshw{$key};
  for ($key){
    s/\s+//g;
   }
  $lshw{$key} = $value;
  }

my $logname   = $lshw{'logicalname'};
print "Logical name\t $logname\n";
```

but I strugle when I come to the line with configurations like:

```
clock: 33Mhz 
width: 32 bits 
capacity: 1Gbit/s 
configuration:autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.3.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s`
```

I was trying a hoh approach, but did not find a solution how to split key/values, as it contains multi word values like `port=twisted pair`.
The key is always a single word.

Can anyone please give me a hint how to solve this?

(thanks simbabque for the strict/warnings hint)

Comment: Is the config key on the left of the `=` always one word?

Comment: Also, you want to use `use strict` and `use warnings` and make your script compile with that please, and then update the code. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: So far your code only gets the `key: value....` stuff, but it does not deal with the individual pairs inside that value. Have you forgotten to add that code to the question?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is to capture all characters after an equal sign which are not followed by the pattern `somekeyname=`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = q{configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.3.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s};

my ($key, $rest) = split /:\s*/, $s, 2;

my %params = ($rest =~ / (\w+) = ((?:. (?! \w+ = ))+) /gx);

use YAML::XS;
print Dump \%params;
```

Output:

```yaml
---
autonegotiation: on
broadcast: yes
driver: igb
driverversion: 5.3.0-k
duplex: full
firmware: 1.63, 0x800009fa
ip: '[REMOVED]'
latency: '0'
link: yes
multicast: yes
port: twisted pair
speed: 1Gbit/s
```

In addition, your initial loop can be improved:

```
 while (<>) {
     next if /^#/; # skip comments
     /\S/ or next; # skip blank lines
     s/^\s+//;
     s/\s+\z//;
     # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to `split` the config string as so

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.3.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s';

say for split /\s+(?=[^\s=]+=)/, $s;
```

#### output

```
configuration:
autonegotiation=on
broadcast=yes
driver=igb
driverversion=5.3.0-k
duplex=full
firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa
ip=[REMOVED]
latency=0
link=yes
multicast=yes
port=twisted pair
speed=1Gbit/s
```

You now have a list of keys and their values, correctly divided by key name. This should be simple to process

Comment: Cool, mastering regex is on my next wish-list ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The approach of Borodin is it.

Just in case you want to parse it with regexp this will work and separates the keys from its values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use strict;
my $s = 'configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.3.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.63, 0x800009fa ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s';

while ($s =~ m/(?<key>[A-Za-z0-9]+)=(?<value>([\/\[\]A-Za-z0-9., -]+)(?= [a-z]+)|([\/\[\]A-Za-z0-9., -]+))/g) {
    print "$+{key} >>  $+{value}\n";
    $s =~ s/$+{key}//;
}
```

**Output**

```
autonegotiation >>  on
broadcast >>  yes
driver >>  igb
driverversion >>  5.3.0-k
duplex >>  full
firmware >>  1.63, 0x800009fa
ip >>  [REMOVED]
latency >>  0
link >>  yes
multicast >>  yes
port >>  twisted pair
speed >>  1Gbit/s
```

**Pros**

- key/value separation

**Cons**

- expensive positive lookahead in regular expression

**Refactoring proposal**

- get rid of complex character group in regex `[\/\[\]A-Za-z0-9., -]`
- get rid of replacement of found patterns in loop